# Repetition of determiner "this"

Tags: determiners

I came across these sentences [here](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/ebsa/laws-and-regulations/laws/affordable-care-act/for-employers-and-advisers/model-notice-for-employers-who-do-not-offer-a-health-plan.pdf) and I wondered if it is OK to repeat the determiner "this". It sounded a little awkward to me.

> If you decide to complete an application for coverage in the
> Marketplace, you will be asked to provide **this information. This
> information** is numbered to correspond to the Marketplace application.

We learned in school to use "the" when the same word appears again so I replaced "this information" with "**the** information" but it is still a little awkward.

> If you decide to complete an application for coverage in the
> Marketplace, you will be asked to provide **this information**. **The
> information** is numbered to correspond to the Marketplace
> application.

Maybe it should be replaced by "it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing it with "it" is unclear what you are referring too. You could be referring to the application or the information. So it might be better to say this instead

> If you decide to complete an application for coverage in the Marketplace, you will be asked to provide this information, which is numbered to correspond to the application.

No need to say "marketplace application" since you already mentioned "application coverage in the marketplace", but you can if you want to, it just might sound a bit repetitive.